# How to customize TMF to call arm gcc toolchain to build the code generated by simulink

Tags: c, gcc, arm, code-generation, simulink

I am using the code generation function in Simulink to generate C code for my model automatically, with the default ert.tlc.

Now the code generation step is done, I want to call the arm gcc toolchain to build the executable. How can I modify the TMF (template makefile) to call arm gcc to build code?

Here are some statements I've changed in the ert_unix.tmf (I use this one because my host is Mac OS)

```
MAKECMD         = /Users/dev/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2013q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
HOST            = ARM
BUILD           = yes
SYS_TARGET_FILE = my_ert.tlc
```

I got an error said 'Make will not be invoked - template makefile is for a different host' when I used it.

Any responses would be greatly helpful for me!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you using ert_unix? This is if you want to build your model for your MAC host, you want to build your model for an ARM target. I think if you use the default ERT target and configure it for ARM in the code generation options it should create an appropriate tmf for you...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I use the ert.tlc to do code generation. And I configure the ert_unix.tmf. So do you mean I should configure the default ert.tmf for building? Its host field is 'PC' and I've tried to change it to 'ARM' then I got an error msg said 'Make will not be invoked - template makefile is for a different host'